# How to get actual URL from a list of routes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-routing

i have a set of routes defined in System.Web.Routing and in need to get the actual url's with the .aspx extension. i've tried this code but i'm doing something wrong here:

```
 var path = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, item.Link, null);
 var link = path.Route.GetVirtualPath(null, null);
 if (link.VirtualPath.ToLower().Contains("~/displaycmspage.aspx?pagename="))
 {
      //do work on url here
 }
```

any idea on how i can do this? The item.link is a custom object where i have the route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so i found the answer :

```
 var path = RouteTable.Routes[item.Link];
 Route ruta = path as Route;
 var link = ruta.RouteHandler as PageRouteHandler;
 if (link.VirtualPath.ToString().ToLower().Contains("~/displaycmspage.aspx?pagename="))
 {
      //do work on url here
 }
```

Comment: Never use `ToLower().Contains()`. Use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` [instead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425.aspx).

Comment: `PageRouteHandler.VirtualPath` is _already_ ` a [string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.pageroutehandler.virtualpath.aspx)!

Comment: - i didn't know about StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase  - thanks
- i know it's already a string i just forgot the ToString() method there because i was constantly changing the code and i didn't do any cleanup. thanks for the remark anyway.

Comment: what is item.Link?

Comment: item.Link is the route name in the routetable